# jQuery post data and send email when user clicks on a button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-ligt selection" id="Amazon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AmazonmodalElem">Select</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".selection").click(function() {
            var myID = $(this).attr('id')
            alert("you clicked the selection: " + myID);

            //start AJAX Post request to post data to the server

            //end of post request

            $.post("post.php", {
                selection: myID
            }, function(data,status){

            $("#message").html(data);
        } );
        //end of AJAX post method

      });
  //end of click event for button selections
  });

</script>
```

PHP

```
  <?php
      $mailTo = "admin@google.com";
      $mailFrom = "no-reply@admin.com";
      $subject = "$_POST["subject"]";
      $message = "someone selected a gift card.";

      mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom);
  ?>
```

Update:
Now I got the PHP to send an email and seems to be working properly. Now, the AJAX success message is not showing up in my HTML element with an ID --> message. Can someone give me pointers to what could be missing in my jQuery code?

Thanks!

Comment: `"$_POST["subject"]"` where your posting the data?

Comment: Two problems, firstly remove the double quotes around `$_POST["subject"]`, secondly you're sending a parameter named `selection`, not `subject`, so it should be `$_POST["selection"]`

Comment: PHP script successfully sends an email to notify me when someone selects a gift, now the user-feedback message doesn't show in my HTML element. Could it be my set up in the Post method or what am I missing in my javascript code?

Comment: Your first questions seems perfectly answerable, and you seem to have resolved the issue. You should add an answer to this question with your updated code. Also, I think you should ask a second question for your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it now and see ajax print successful message as you requested...

```
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selection).click(function(){  
var myID = $(this).attr('id');
alert("you clicked the selection: " + myID);
var datasend = "myID="+ myID;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'post.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
            alert(msg); 

                $('#message').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

            }


        });


});

});




</script>


 <body>
<div id="message"> </div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-ligt selection" id="Amazon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AmazonmodalElem">Select</button>


</body>
```

php

```
 <?php
      $mailTo = "admin@google.com";
      $mailFrom = "no-reply@admin.com";
     // $subject = $_POST['subject'];
$subject = 'my subject head';
      $message = "someone selected a gift card.";

      mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom);

     echo "Email successfully sent";
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the problem was not posting the data --> button attribute in the PHP data response, so I wasn't seeing a response in the developer Network panel in the browser.